# Allow user to do pinchin and pinchout

Tags: asp.net, ipad, html

I am working on ipad application(using Asp.net framework and HTML5).

I can't do pinch-in and pinch-out of my application.

I have used the `meta tag` also but still it didn't help.

By default ipad provides pinch to zoom on safari. But for the application on which I am working on, its not happening at all.

Below is the meta tag which I am using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add minimum and maximum `scale` parameters to the meta tag, just like below

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0">`

Comment: Thanks chiller.but it dint help me.any other solution?

Comment: Add another parameter user-scalable=yes inside the value of content just like below code <br/> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0 user-scalable=yes">` I hope this will sure to help you if not let me know again....

Comment: I have tried that also.From past two weeks i am working on the same.but didnt get the solution yet.Any other ways of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried it with sample application, just for doing Zoom in and Zoom out.

Comment: yeah.I have tried.Its not working for the application.If i create a new page den in that page its working fine.

Comment: That looks really strange for me; may i have your code on some way so that i will try to work on that

Answer (score 0):

Try The below head section and let me know what happens, 
`<!DOCTYPE HTML >`
`<html>`
`<head>`
    `<title>Untitled</title>`
    `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
    `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.6,user-scalable=yes">`
    `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="YES">`
`</head>`
`<body></body>`
`</html>`

Comment: This is working fine. pinch to zoom is happening.As i said before its not working for the application on which i am working.Do i need to do any other settings?

Comment: It may be your script , i guess. Have you used `event.preventDefault()` in your script anywhere?....

Comment: no.I am using mobile jquery.is that the reason behind this issue?

Comment: Hi chiller,I got to know what is the issue.I have included the below script in the application.     <script src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a2.js" type="text/javascript"></script> If i comment one of these script tags ,i am able to do zoomin and zoomout via pinch.Now i am looking for a a solution for pinch which is supported by mobile jquery.

Comment: I have used this [jQuery Mobile lib](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) and i didnt face any problem as you said....But meanwhile i 'll look into the lib which you said, what's the cause of your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your tips chiller.For mobile jquery we need to override mobile init before loading mobile jquery.My problem is solved.For solution refer these links : http://chillburn.com.au/blog/enabling-the-pinch-zoom-for-the-ipad-iphone-while-using-jquery-mobile/        http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 0):

For solution have  a look at these links:

http://chillburn.com.au/blog/enabling-the-pinch-zoom-for-the-ipad-iphone-while-using-jquery-mobile/

jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html